# why am I getting undefined instead of null

Tags: javascript

Hey guys today is my first day of learning to code, so I'm sure this is a super dumb question. I'm following along freecodecamp beginner javascript video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PkZNo7MFNFg&t=678 and at 11:20, when after writing console.log(a) on line 3 and running the script he gets null then 7 but i get undefined then 7.

Anybody know why?

[image]

Comment: The image posted is my script.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: @Pizza910 Welcome to StackOverflow. Code in external sources or screenshots of code are not allowed here. Please post relevant code snippets in the question itself.

Comment: I wouldn't worry about it - I think you should get 'undefined' so there's something odd he's doing to get 'null'. ( In JS there is a difference between null and undefined, but as a beginner it would just mean that they do not have a usable value yet.

Answer (score 1):

The tutorial video is wrong. I don't know why it shows `null` for the tutor, it shouldn't.

Uninitialized variables are `undefined` in JavaScript, not `null`.

```js
var a;
console.log(a); // prints undefined
```

It would only be `null` if explictly set to `null`:

```js
var a = null;
console.log(a); // prints null
```

Answer (score 0):

`var a;` declares the variable `a` but does not assign it value. Its value is undefined, which is why you see "undefined" in the console.

Once you assign it a value (e.g. `a = 7;`) then it has a value.

Answer (score 0):

Javascript will never assign `null`, in order to get `null` you'd actually need to do it yourself from code.

`undefined` is the default value for a variable that has been declared but not assigned a value to.

`null` is an assignment value, you can assign it to any variable explicitly making it "empty".